# Laravel: how I can write my onw function with own query on my model?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Example:
I wanna create my own function for laravel model like:

(original query)

```
SELECT
   AVG(persons_positions.points)
FROM
    positions
INNER JOIN persons_positions ON (
    positions.id = persons_positions.position_id
)
WHERE positions.country = 1
AND persons_positions.person_id = 2
```

(model class)

```
class Menedzher extends Model {
    function oh ($x) {
        return DB::table('positions')
            ->join('persons_positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'persons_positions.position_id')
            ->where('positions.country', $x) // see here
            ->where('persons_positions.person_id', '=', $this->id ) // see it!!
            ->select(DB::raw('AVG(persons_positions.hits)'));

    }
}
```

**and to use it:**

Menedzher::get(1)->oh(3)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to fetch average position for each person?

Comment: well, this is a example. I wanna use my LEFT, INNER joins with own select.. some complex query. Hoy i can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Make one relationship in your Position Model like below

```
public function oh() {
        return $this->hasOne('persons_positions')
            ->selectRaw('avg(hits) as hits, person_id')
            ->groupBy('person_id');
    }
```

Then do this in controller

```
$user = Position::with('oh')->get();
```

Comment: Well, i need use JOIN. How i can set it?

Comment: And, can you see the params?

Comment: You dont need to use join here

Comment: Well, i want use my own query.